# Node is not updating in the node folder of ui.frontend AEM REACT REPO doing mvn install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, maven, npm, aem

[image: Folder Structure of node folder in ui.frontend]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (npm install) on project aem-mgd.ui.frontend: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Omnichannellatest\ocl-frontend-web\ui.frontend\node\node.exe" (in directory "C:\Omnichannellatest\ocl-frontend-web\ui.frontend"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]

[image: node in node folder ui.frontend]

mvn clean install
node version : 16.15.1
npm version: 8.11.0

In the node folder copy the exe file https://nodejs.org/de/blog/release/v16.15.1/ 64 bit depends on your system config 64bit / 32bit and then open the file from node folder and close it once done run mvn clean install its working

Comment: In the node folder copy the exe file https://nodejs.org/de/blog/release/v16.15.1/ 64 bit depends on your system config 64bit / 32bit and then open the file from node folder and close it once done run mvn clean install its working